# python BankAccount program

Tags: python

Create a class called BankAccount

Create a constructor that takes in an integer and assigns this to a `balance` property.

Create a method called `deposit` that takes in cash deposit amount and updates the balance accordingly.

Create a method called `withdraw` that takes in cash withdrawal amount and updates the balance accordingly. if amount is greater than balance return `"invalid transaction"`

Create a subclass MinimumBalanceAccount of the BankAccount class

---

hey friends i'm learning python online and i wanted to try this homework but i'm having some chalenges to compile it and this is my code:

```
import unittest
class AccountBalanceTestCases(unittest.TestCase):
  def setUp(self):
    self.my_account = BankAccount(90)
    
  def test_balance(self):
    self.assertEqual(self.my_account.balance, 90, msg='Account Balance Invalid')
    
  def test_deposit(self):
    self.my_account.deposit(90)
    self.assertEqual(self.my_account.balance, 180, msg='Deposit method inaccurate')
    
  def test_withdraw(self):
    self.my_account.withdraw(40)
    self.assertEqual(self.my_account.balance, 50, msg='Withdraw method inaccurate')
    
  def test_invalid_operation(self):
    self.assertEqual(self.my_account.withdraw(1000), "invalid transaction", msg='Invalid transaction')
  
  def test_sub_class(self):
    self.assertTrue(issubclass(MinimumBalanceAccount, BankAccount), msg='No true subclass of BankAccount')
```

and this is the error i get from it:

> Your Code Solution Has Errors
>
> THERE IS AN ERROR/BUG IN YOUR CODE
>
> Results:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "python/nose2/bin/nose2", line 8, in 
    discover()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nose2/main.py", line 300, in discover
    return main(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nose2/main.py", line 100, in __init__
    super(PluggableTestProgram, self).__init__(**kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/unittest/main.py", line 94, in __init__
    self.parseArgs(argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nose2/main.py", line 133, in parseArgs
    self.createTests()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nose2/main.py", line 258, in createTests
    self.testNames, self.module)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nose2/loader.py", line 67, in loadTestsFromNames
    for name in event.names]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nose2/loader.py", line 82, in loadTestsFromName
    result = self.session.hooks.loadTestsFromName(event)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nose2/events.py", line 224, in __call__
    result = getattr(plugin, self.method)(event)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nose2/plugins/loader/testclasses.py", line 119, in loadTestsFromName
    result = util.test_from_name(name, module)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nose2/util.py", line 106, in test_from_name
    parent, obj = object_from_name(name, module)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nose2/util.py", line 117, in object_from_name
    module = __import__('.'.join(parts_copy))
  File "/home/ubuntu/Applications/andelabs-server/tmp/5783854141a07c1400924f81-565b07b72568f41500779d20-test.py", line 4, in 
    from tmp.andelabs_5783854141a07c1400924f81_565b07b72568f41500779d20 import *
  File "/home/ubuntu/Applications/andelabs-server/tmp/andelabs_5783854141a07c1400924f81_565b07b72568f41500779d20.py", line 2
    def __init__(self,  balance = 90):
      ^
IndentationError: expected an indented block
```

please me with some guidelines to correct it.

Comment: The error message clearly tells us that the problem is in the code that actually describes the `BankAccount` class, but you showed us some code for testing that class.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that there is an indentation issue with the module you are importing. The only way to fix this is by editing the file itself and checking the indentation, especially on line 2 **as stated in the error message**.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that, on line 2, you are using 2 spaces instead of indenting the block of code starting with `def setUp(self):`. Instead, you should use an indent (press tab). Unlike Java or C, Python cares about indentation when compiling code.